# Running slow with intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Trying to optimize a query it is updaing the records in table A based on the INTERSECT on two data sets.

```
UPDATE #TableA
SET IsFlag = CASE WHEN ISNULL(RJobFlag, 0) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM #TableA AS ABC
    OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT 1 RJobFlag 
                    WHERE EXISTS (

                                    SELECT ABC.COLUMN1,ABC.COLUMN2,ABC.COLUMN3,ABC.COLUMN4,ABC.COLUMN5,ABC.COLUMN6,ABC.COLUMN7,ABC.COLUMN8,ABC.COLUMN8,ABC.COLUMN9,ABC.COLUMN10,StudentID,SubjectID
                                    INTERSECT
                                    SELECT XYZ.COLUMN1,XYZ.COLUMN2,XYZ.COLUMN3,XYZ.COLUMN4,XYZ.COLUMN5,XYZ.COLUMN6,XYZ.COLUMN7,XYZ.COLUMN8,XYZ.COLUMN8,XYZ.COLUMN9,XYZ.COLUMN10,StudentID,SubjectID
                                    FROM #TableB AS XYZ
                                    WHERE XYZ.COLUMN1 = (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #TableC MNOP WHERE MNOP.StudentID = ABC.StudentID)

                                    AND StudentID = ABC.StudentID
                                    AND SubjectID = ABC.SubjectID )

                    ) Subquery
WHERE ABC.COLUMN1= '2'
```

Appretiated if you have some ideas to better optimize it. 
Thanks

Comment: What version of *SQL Server* are you using?  2008 or 2005?  Please don't tag both.

Comment: And how do you mean *better optimize*?  Is it performing slowly?  Not giving the correct results?  What's wrong with the query you have?

Comment: Have you determined that it is the `INTERSECT` that makes it slow and nothing else?

Comment: using 2008R2 version

Comment: What does your query plan look like?

Comment: Yes, it is the intesect between the tables. as it has huge data in them. Will recursive cte help. Not sure what other option i have apart from intersect and inner joining between each columns.

Comment: did you try the inner join already?

Comment: yes, i tried inner join too. And its much more slower. intersect is better optimized than inner join.

Comment: @sqlsleepless Please post a screenshot or the XML of the query plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be worse never know.

```
UPDATE  tA
SET     IsFlag = COALESCE(RJobFlag, 0)
FROM    #TableA tA
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 1 RJobFlag, * 
                FROM #TableB tB 
                WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT * 
                                FROM #TableC tC 
                                WHERE tC.ID = tB.COLUMN1 AND tC.StudentID = tB.StudentID)
            ) tB 
                ON tA.StudentID = tB.StudentID
                AND tA.SubjectID = tB.SubjectID
                AND tA.COLUMN1 = tB.COLUMN1
                AND tA.COLUMN2 = tB.COLUMN2
                AND tA.COLUMN3 = tB.COLUMN3
                AND tA.COLUMN4 = tB.COLUMN4
                AND tA.COLUMN5 = tB.COLUMN5
                AND tA.COLUMN6 = tB.COLUMN6
                AND tA.COLUMN7 = tB.COLUMN7
                AND tA.COLUMN8 = tB.COLUMN8
                AND tA.COLUMN9 = tB.COLUMN9
                AND tA.COLUMN10 = tB.COLUMN10
```

If #TableA has a bunch of records and you're using outer apply or outer join every time you update it will be slow since it has to update every single record.  maybe there's a way to only update the records that have changed?